# Why is my SQL data returning undefined in my array methods?

Tags: sql, node.js, arrays, undefined

[The First array returned when I console log person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GW1L.png)

[The second array that returns when I console log person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWGSG.png)

I am trying to create a function that pulls the data from 2 tables in my SQL database. I am using async/await, which is still new to me. The issue is somewhere in the two array methods; for some reason they are returning data as undefined.

```
async function updateRole() {
console.log('hi');
//cycle through both arrays and create new arrays with same information using maps
//return object with employee and role info
const allEmployees = await db.promise().query(`SELECT * FROM employees`);
const allRoles = await db.promise().query(`SELECT * FROM roles`);
console.log(allEmployees);
const employeeChoices = allEmployees.map((person) => {
    return {
        name: `${person.first_name} ${person.last_name}`,
        value: person.id
        }
})

const roleChoices = allRoles.map((role) => {
    return {
        name: role.title,
        value: role.id
    }
})
const { employeeId, roleId } = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
        type: 'list',
        name: 'employeeId',
        message: 'Which employee would you like to update?',
        choices: employeeChoices
    }, 
    {
        type: 'list',
        name: 'roleId',
        message: 'What is their new role?',
        choices: roleChoices
    }])

await db.promise().query(`UPDATE employees SET role_id = ? WHERE id = ?`, [roleId, employeeId])
console.log('Successfully updated employee!');
askQuestions();
```

Update: I added screenshots fo the console log for person. role returns the same format, but obviously different data. I am unsure what the array of ColumnDefinition objects does, or why it's there.

Comment: Can you please provide console logs of ```person``` and ```role``` when using in map ?

Comment: @PawanSharma I have updated my question with the console logs